# How to execute a rails action when html button is clicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I am trying to clean an array when an html button is clicked. I have this controller:

```
class InfoController < ApplicationController
  $names = {}
  def show

    render :print
  end

  def as
    @name = params[:myinfo][:name]
    @number = params[:myinfo][:number]
    $names[@name] = @number
    render :test 

  end

  def clean
    $names = {}
  end

  def add
  end
end
```

How would I go about executing the `clean` action when the button inside this form is clicked?

```
<h1>Info print</h1>
<%= form_for :myinfo do |a| %>
  <%= a.label :name %>
  <%= a.text_field :name %><br>
  <%= a.label :number%>
  <%= a.text_field :number%><br>
  <%= a.submit %>
<%end%>

<form>
  <input type="button" onClick="">
</form>

<%= $names.each do |key, val|%>
  <%=key%> &nbsp 
  <%=val%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Use `button_to` and provide a `info_clean_path` as an argument which also needs to be defined in your `routes`. For more info on `button_to` check this api docs http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
<form>
    <%= link_to "clean", clean_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary'%> # you can add btn class if you are using bootstarp 
</form>
```

**routes.rb:**

```
get 'clean' => "info#clean"
```

Comment: can you explain the section `:class => 'btn btn-primary'` please

Comment: @ErielMarimon It is a `button` which make anchor link as button. That style will apply only if you are using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

My Rails is a little rusty, but I'm thinking something like `<%= button_to "clean", info_clean_path %>` will work, provided that `InfoController#clean` has a defined route of `info_clean_path`.